# Adding argument (post_status) to the loop

Tags: php, loops, arguments

I'm helping my collegue with his wordpress site. The case is pretty simple: add an attribute (post_status => "future") to the loop. The only issue is that I cannot find where I should do that (as i dont see any proper wp_query() statement to do that. Please take a look on the template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Render the blog layouts.
 *
 * @author      ThemeFusion
 * @package     Avada/Templates
 * @version     1.0
 */

// Do not allow directly accessing this file.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit( 'Direct script access denied.' ); }

global $wp_query;

// Set the correct post container layout classes.
$blog_layout = avada_get_blog_layout();
$post_class  = 'fusion-post-' . $blog_layout;

$container_class = 'fusion-blog-layout-' . $blog_layout . ' ';
if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout ) {
    $container_class = 'fusion-blog-layout-' . $blog_layout . ' fusion-blog-layout-' . $blog_layout . '-' . Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_grid_columns' ) . ' isotope ';
}

// Set class for scrolling type.
if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_pagination_type' ) == 'Infinite Scroll' ||
     Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_pagination_type' ) == 'load_more_button'
) {
    $container_class .= 'fusion-blog-infinite fusion-posts-container-infinite ';
} else {
    $container_class .= 'fusion-blog-pagination ';
}

if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'featured_images' ) ) {
    $container_class .= 'fusion-blog-no-images ';
}

// Add the timeline icon.
if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
    echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-icon"><i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i></div>';
}

if ( is_search() &&
     Avada()->settings->get( 'search_results_per_page' )
) {
    $number_of_pages = ceil( $wp_query->found_posts / Avada()->settings->get( 'search_results_per_page' ) );
} else {
    $number_of_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
}

echo '<div id="posts-container" class="' . $container_class . 'fusion-blog-archive fusion-clearfix" data-pages="' . $number_of_pages . '">';

if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
    // Initialize the time stamps for timeline month/year check.
    $post_count = 1;
    $prev_post_timestamp = null;
    $prev_post_month = null;
    $prev_post_year = null;
    $first_timeline_loop = false;

    // Add the container that holds the actual timeline line.
    echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-line"></div>';
}

    // Start the main loop.
while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post();
    // Set the time stamps for timeline month/year check.
    $alignment_class = '';
    if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        $post_timestamp = get_the_time( 'U' );
        $post_month     = date( 'n', $post_timestamp );
        $post_year      = get_the_date( 'Y' );
        $current_date   = get_the_date( 'Y-n' );

        // Set the correct column class for every post.
        if ( $post_count % 2 ) {
            $alignment_class = 'fusion-left-column';
        } else {
            $alignment_class = 'fusion-right-column';
        }

        // Set the timeline month label.
        if ( $prev_post_month != $post_month || $prev_post_year != $post_year ) {

            if ( $post_count > 1 ) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '<h3 class="fusion-timeline-date">' . get_the_date( Avada()->settings->get( 'timeline_date_format' ) ) . '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="fusion-collapse-month">';
        }
    }

    // Set the has-post-thumbnail if a video is used. This is needed if no featured image is present.
    $thumb_class = '';
    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pyre_video', true ) ) {
        $thumb_class = ' has-post-thumbnail';
    }

    $post_classes = $post_class . ' ' . $alignment_class . ' ' . $thumb_class . ' post fusion-clearfix';
    ob_start();
    post_class( $post_classes );
    $post_classes = ob_get_clean();

    echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" ' . $post_classes . '>';
    // Add an additional wrapper for grid layout border.
    if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-post-wrapper">';
    }

        // Get featured images for all but large-alternate layout.
    if ( ( ( is_search() && Avada()->settings->get( 'search_featured_images' ) ) || ( ! is_search() && Avada()->settings->get( 'featured_images' ) ) ) && 'large-alternate' == $blog_layout ) {
        get_template_part( 'new-slideshow' );
    }

        // Get the post date and format box for alternate layouts.
    if ( 'large-alternate' == $blog_layout || 'medium-alternate' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-date-and-formats">';

        /**
         * The avada_blog_post_date_adn_format hook.
         *
         * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_date - 10 (outputs the HTML for the date box).
         * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_format - 15 (outputs the HTML for the post format box).
         */
        do_action( 'avada_blog_post_date_and_format' );

        echo '</div>';
    }

    // Get featured images for all but large-alternate layout.
    if ( ( ( is_search() && Avada()->settings->get( 'search_featured_images' ) ) || ( ! is_search() && Avada()->settings->get( 'featured_images' ) ) ) && 'large-alternate' != $blog_layout ) {
        get_template_part( 'new-slideshow' );
    }

        // The post-content-wrapper is only needed for grid and timeline.
    if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout || 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">';
    }

    // Add the circles for timeline layout.
    if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-circle"></div>';
        echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-arrow"></div>';
    }

    echo '<div class="fusion-post-content post-content">';

    // Render the post title.
    echo avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() );


                        $categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
                        $separator = ', ';
                        $output = '';
                        $numItems = count($categories);
                        $i = 0;
                        if($categories){
                            foreach($categories as $category) {
                                $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
                                if(++$i !== $numItems) {
                                    $output .= $separator;
                                }
                            }
                        }   

    echo ( '<div class="lista-koncert-podtytul">' . $output . '</div>' );                       

    // Render post meta for grid and timeline layouts.
    if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout || 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'grid_timeline' );

        if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta' ) && ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_author' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_date' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_cats' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_tags' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) ) && 0 < Avada()->settings->get( 'excerpt_length_blog' ) ) {
            echo '<div class="fusion-content-sep"></div>';
        }
        // Render post meta for alternate layouts.
    } elseif ( 'large-alternate' == $blog_layout || 'medium-alternate' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'alternate' );
    }

    echo '<div class="fusion-post-content-container">';

    /**
     * The avada_blog_post_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_content - 10 (outputs the post content wrapped with a container).
     */
    do_action( 'avada_blog_post_content' );

    echo '<a href="' . get_post_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">Zobacz więcej &gt;</a>';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>'; // End post-content.

    if ( 'medium' == $blog_layout || 'medium-alternate' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>';
    }

    // Render post meta data according to layout.
    if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta' ) && ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_author' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_date' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_cats' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_tags' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) || Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) ) ) {
        echo '<div class="fusion-meta-info">';
        if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout || 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
            // Render read more for grid/timeline layouts.
            echo '<div class="fusion-alignleft">';
            if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) {
                $link_target = '';
                if ( fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ||
                fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ) {
                    $link_target = ' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"';
                }
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="fusion-read-more"' . $link_target . '>' . apply_filters( 'avada_blog_read_more_link', esc_attr__( 'Read More', 'Avada' ) ) . '</a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';

            // Render comments for grid/timeline layouts.
            echo '<div class="fusion-alignright">';
            if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) ) {
                if ( ! post_password_required( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                    comments_popup_link( '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;0', '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;' . __( '1', 'Avada' ), '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;%' );
                } else {
                    echo '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;' . esc_attr__( 'Protected', 'Avada' );
                }
            }

            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            // Render all meta data for medium and large layouts.
            if ( 'large' == $blog_layout || 'medium' == $blog_layout ) {
                echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'standard' );
            }

            // Render read more for medium/large and medium/large alternate layouts.
            echo '<div class="fusion-alignright">';
            if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) {
                $link_target = '';
                if ( fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ||
                fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ) {
                    $link_target = ' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"';
                }
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="fusion-read-more"' . $link_target . '>' . apply_filters( 'avada_read_more_name', esc_attr__( 'Read More', 'Avada' ) ) . '</a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>'; // End meta-info.
    }
    if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout || 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '</div>'; // End post-content-wrapper.
    }
    if ( 'grid' == $blog_layout ) {
        echo '</div>'; // End post-wrapper.
    }
    echo '</article>'; // End post.

    // Adjust the timestamp settings for next loop.
    if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout ) {
        $prev_post_timestamp = $post_timestamp;
        $prev_post_month     = $post_month;
        $prev_post_year      = $post_year;
        $post_count++;
    }
endwhile; // End have_posts().

if ( 'timeline' == $blog_layout && 1 < $post_count ) {
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>'; // End posts-container.

// If infinite scroll with "load more" button is used.
if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_pagination_type' ) == 'load_more_button' ) {
    echo '<div class="fusion-load-more-button fusion-blog-button fusion-clearfix">' . apply_filters( 'avada_load_more_posts_name', esc_attr__( 'Load More Posts', 'Avada' ) ) . '</div>';
}

// Get the pagination.
fusion_pagination( $pages = '', $range = 2 );

wp_reset_query();
```

in this case - which part of template i should edit? seriously have no clue where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress works with a different methodology: `hooks` and `filters`.

So the manipulation of the wp_query doesn't necessary appear in the template file, rather in a file named functions.php (Usually, it can be in almost any file - especially if its an advanced theme). Finding it might be a mess.

You can try to customize the current loop and hope it has no special hooks related:

Instead of:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post();
```

Write:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'future' ) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting it :)